# Eclipse Can't Set Debug Breakpoint - Greyed out Says: Chosen Op Not Enabled DS-5 Debug Plugin

Tags: eclipse, debugging, android-ndk

I was successfully setting DS-5 Debug breakpoints using community edition of `DS-5 Debugger`.

However, now I try to run and its grayed-out.  I can set C/C++, but no longer DS-5 debug breakpoints.

All the debug options now show `Chosen operation not enabled`.  It was working, I just restarted computer and now I can't.

I've tried new project, C++ project, new workspace, but I don't seem to be able to set this type of breakpoint anymore.

Update:  Looks like it was just the debug configuration needs to be connected before setting DS-5 debug breakpoints.

Comment: If you were able to fix the issue yourself, please post the solution as an answer and accept it. Don't post it as a part of question.

Answer (score 0):

ARM DS-5 Debug perspective acts weird sometimes.

When your app not running first you have to set debug points then Run your application and after activating debug points by click on their checkboxes you should connect to device with ARM DS-5 Debug configuration.

If you do in this order you'll be able to hit one of your debug points as long as there are no compilation or runtime errors.